# Google Maps marker click listener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to add click event to Google Map markers, I'm using cordova in my app. Any way recommended in the documentation is not working... unless I make the marker draggable (then it works like gold) and I can't do that. I found that it was an issue a long, long time ago in [2011...](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3148)

I think something had to be done with that since 2011. Do you have any idea?

Working piece of code below:

```
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat, coords.lng);
            var markerOptions = angular.extend({
                map: map,
                position: position,
                title: name,
                draggable: true

            }, DrawingOptions.marker);

            var googleMarker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);

            var marker = {
                Id: id,
                Type: type,
                marker: googleMarker,
                circle: new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions),
            };

            marker.marker.addListener('click', function () {
                addInfoModal();

            });
```

I also tried to make a function adding listener, but it won't work. I was also thinking about not-so-graceful solution - making marker draggable, but actually preventing action while dragging, but this isn't working and it looks bad in code.

Have you heard of something helpful in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Seem your function is not right.

try without function simply adding the listener this way :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(googleMarker, 'click', function (event) {
                alert('click');
            });
```

Comment: Thanks, but tried that, not working. The function I used is mentioned in  Google API documentation. [link]https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers  
I also tried setting listener in options as it was shown in other solutions, but setting draggable to true was only thing activating the click event...

Comment: Try with a simple alert like this alert('click');` . I'm sure this working.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help, but I tried literally all forms of adding listener and it just can't go inside listener function. If addInfoModal was wrong, it wouldn't work when draggable is set to on.